# ArCore / Sceneform - How to add Time Listener to Animated 3D model?

Tags: android, android-animation, arcore, sceneform

I've successfully rendered a 3d model and added an animation to it. My question is how can I listen the what part of the animation (time say the animation is 5 seconds, how to listen if it's at 3 seconds) is playing.

```
 ModelRenderable.builder()
                .setSource(this, Uri.parse("anim5.sfb"))
                .build()
                .thenAccept(modelRenderable -> {
                    personRenderable = modelRenderable;

                    SkeletonNode skeletonNode = new SkeletonNode();
                    skeletonNode.setLocalPosition(NODE_STARTING_LOCAL_POSITION);
                    skeletonNode.setRenderable(personRenderable);
                    mScene.addChild(skeletonNode);
                     
                })
                .exceptionally(throwable -> {
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this,
                            "Unable to load Card renderable" + throwable, Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                    );
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
                    return null;
                });
```

```
private ModelAnimator mModelAnimator;
private AnimationData mAnimationData;

@OnClick(R.id.btn_start_animation)
    public void startAnimation(){
        Log.d(TAG, "startAnimation: " + personRenderable.getAnimationDataCount());

        if(personRenderable != null){
            mAnimationData = personRenderable.getAnimationData(0);


            mModelAnimator = new ModelAnimator(mAnimationData, personRenderable);
            mModelAnimator.setRepeatCount(50);
            mModelAnimator.start();
        }

    }
```

After checking the docs, it seems there is a `TimeAnimator` class. With a `TimeListener`, but I'm not sure if I can apply this to the `ModelRenderable`.

```
TimeAnimator timeAnimator = new TimeAnimator();
            timeAnimator.setTimeListener(new TimeAnimator.TimeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onTimeUpdate(TimeAnimator animation, long totalTime, long deltaTime) {
                    
                }
            });
```